# Reshape channels into pixels with Pytorch

Tags: image, pytorch, reshape, tensor

By default pytorch encodes images as `[batch_size, channels, height, width]` tensors. I want to build a network that upsamples `[b, c, h, w]` image to `[b, c, 2*h, 2*w]`. The way I implement this is by first producing `[b, 4*c, h, w]` and then I want to reshape it to `[b, c, 2*h, 2*w]` in such  a way that each `4*c`-channel pixel becomes 4 **neighbouring** `c`-channel pixels such that the neighbours form a small **square** rather than a **line** of 4 pixels. Unfortunately the `reshape()` function arranges the neighbours into a line.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using nn.Upsample: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Upsample.html

You can use a scaling factor of 2 like in the doc. Not sure if the dimensions in this example are the same as yours, but inputs of the form N,C,H,W are also accepted.

```
>>> input = torch.arange(1, 5, dtype=torch.float32).view(1, 1, 2, 2)
>>> input
tensor([[[[ 1.,  2.],
          [ 3.,  4.]]]])

>>> m = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='nearest')
>>> m(input)
tensor([[[[ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.],
          [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.],
          [ 3.,  3.,  4.,  4.],
          [ 3.,  3.,  4.,  4.]]]])
´´´
```

Comment: This approach makes a copy of the same pixel. In my case I don't want to copy anything. I want to reshape channels into pixels. Each `4c` channel is `[r0,g0,b0, r1,g1,b1, r2,g2,b2, r3,g3,b3]`, which should then be reshaped to `[r0,g0,b0], [r1,g1,b1], [r2,g2,b2], [r3,g3,b3]`, except that this now arranges pixels into a line. I want them to form a square.